# Substituting curl parameters in python request

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to modify a curl request

```
curl \
   -D- \
   -u 'username:password' \
   -X POST \
   --data '{"fields": {"project":{"key": "key"},"summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.","description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API","issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}}}' \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   https://instance/rest/api/2/issue/
```

I'd like to know how to substitute the `-u` parameter in a request like

```
import requests

url = 'https://instance/rest/api/2/issue/'
body = dict("INSERT_BODY_HERE")

response = requests.post(url, body)
```

Comment: I'd look here: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#authentication Maybe the `auth=(user, password)` parameter will help?

Comment: You can try: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: @hidden_machine this is a really useful website. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated code below to convert your curl request to python requests:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = "https://instance/rest/api/2/issue"

payload = {"fields": {
    "project": {"key": "key"},
    "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
    "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
    "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}
}}
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
```

Like mentioned in the comments by [@hidden_machine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16348170/hidden-machine), there is also a cool website as well where you can pass the curl request and it will generate the code for you in various languages - [curl.trillworks.com](https://curl.trillworks.com/) .